# stretchable histogram overlaying a picture

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0, wpf-controls

I'm in the process of making a WPF program that:

1. can scan a bitmap image, pixel-by-pixel, and assign it a data value (0-255)
2. design a class that allows panning and zooming of the picture
3. create a histogram, from the data values, that overlays the bitmap image.

I was able to do all three, however the issue that I am having is that the histogram doesn't dynamically (I think that's the word for it) stretch as I re-size the main window. Actually, nothing stretches to the correct size in the main window (the bitmap image just re-centers itself while keeping the same size). The histogram originally started as a transparent canvas that had many rectangle children. I changed it to a grid but am getting the same results as the canvas; the rectangles don't want to stretch horizontally or vertically. If I do set a horz/vert alignment the histogram disappears altogether. Can anyone help with this problem?

Comment: Care to explain how? You can post an answer to your own question if you'd like to share...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up making a class that was a derivative of the canvas class i cave it some rendering overrides and a paint method that took into account the actual width and height of the window.